# \addbibresource undefined control sequence with MikTex

Tags: biblatex, miktex

I'm using the latest version of MikTex, which comes with biblatex, and I can't get biblatex to work. It breaks in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{soarBib.bib}
\title{A title}
\subtitle{Some Subtitle}
\author{Nate Glenn}
\date{May 16, 2011}
\begin{document}
```

The errors are:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \addbibresource
l.5 \addbibresource
{soarBib.bib}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
...

! Package biblatex Error: File 'literatureReview.bbl' not created by biblatex.
See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
```

Comment: Could it be that you didn't *update* your "latest" MiKTeX version (2.9) for some time? `\addbibresource` was introduced in biblatex v1.2, which was released in February 2011. (BTW, load hyperref *after*  biblatex.)

Comment: you could try `\bibliography{soarBib}` instead of `\addbibresource{}`

Comment: To see the current version of biblatex use the command `\listfiles`.

Comment: Your preamble works fine for me (current miktex 2.9). Check in the log file the location of your biblatex version. Is it in the main miktex root or in a user root? In the second case you will have to run the update manager as user to get the newest version.

Comment: @lockstep- why do I need to load hyperref after biblatex?

Comment: @Nate: (Sorry for the late answer, somehow missed your comment) As a rule, hyperref needs to be loaded as the last package. There are exceptions to this rule (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) for details), but biblatex isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that biblatex isn't included in MikTeX 2.8. It was solved by updating to 2.9.

Comment: These sorts of "Thanks" answers are discouraged on this site.

Comment: @Seamus: IMHO it qualifies as an answer because it's states that the issue was the older MikTeX version. However, I'm still tempted to close the question as "too localized" because it seems to be simply a case of not-up-to-date package(s).

Comment: @Martin @Nate sorry, I might have misread the answer. The way it's written doesn't make it clear that this is an answer. Perhaps it could be written to say "The problem is that `biblatex` isn't included in MikTeX 2.8. It was solved by updating to 2.9."

Comment: @Seamus, @Nate: I agree that rephrasing would improve the post. Also Q&A's should be limited to one issue, so the `ifxetex` issue is misplaced. @Seamus: Also note my update on my last comment.

Comment: Sorry. Edited to follow standards.